Mirroring disk between computers
I want to have a logical disk (using LVM) that is mirrored between two computers.  That is, I want one filesystem that has complete copies on two different computers.
I want to do this on Linux, preferably without significant add-ons.
Ideally, I would like to be able to access it from either computer, locally, and NFS publish it for other machines.
One solution might be to publish the "disk" on one machine with iSCSI or network block device (NBD) or the like, use RAID mirroring on that, then a filesystem, and then NFS to share it with everyone.  This does everything but local access (but can be reconfigured if the normal master is dead), and is easily extended to more machines.
Another might be two independent filesystems synced by cron jobs running rsync.
What I am hoping for is an advanced distributed filesystem solution, that can also merge changes if one node is disconnected, edited, and reconnected.
Edit: The basic requirements:  I currently keep all my network management information on one computer.  Every so often, it has trouble booting.  (It is so old, the battery has died (and the big storm last Thursday (Maine) took out power).)  So I would like to automatically distribute the data around to other machines in the network, so that as long as one works, I can get it all.

I think the cron job / rsync solution sounds pretty clever: Low complexity, few opportunities for inconsistencies to creep in, you don't seem to need tight synchronization, it's no problem if the network is down in between synchronization runs… Do you foresee any problems with that, David? There's certainly more involved distributed storage solutions with hot or cold standby, even completely transparent failover, and "local" is also a stretchable term, but to be honest, things like ceph are a number larger than what I've been doing, and the requirements you posted don't really suggest you…

… would need any of this. But this might really be an issue of me not understanding the requirements. What I can say with certainty is that unless you do something very special file system-wise, then you can't just mount the filesystem some other system has had in use and expect consistent state.

I mean the honest recommendation here is not to use the least reliable of your computers for management. You probably realize that and have your reasons, so…

(I really don't know your financial situation, so I'll be very careful with recommending solutions that require spending money, but then again, you're thinking about RAID mirroring data where all you need is a few megabytes of data. So really, you should consider buying a used business notebook or desktop, and install a fresh, good SSD inside. In Europe, 4 to 8 years thinkpads T-series devices are relatively cheap, and near indestructible little management machines.)

(here is a selection (<€150) of such used machines with at tolerable display resolution. Beware the red text – it says things like "bright spot" or "loudspeakers dysfunctional". Of course, you can have the greatest management laptop, STILL do backups!)

@MarcusMüller The current machine is not unreliable.  It is simply old.  It may also be fastest (per CPU) machine, as I bought well for this one.  It is my main desktop machine.  At this point, I just need to find a replacement battery.  And I would consider an SSD to be much LESS reliable.

Use dRAID with zfs.

dRAID is a variant of raidz that provides integrated distributed hot spares which allows for faster resilvering while retaining the benefits of raidz. A dRAID vdev is constructed from multiple internal raidz groups, each with D data devices and P parity devices. These groups are distributed over all of the children in order to fully utilize the available disk performance. This is known as parity declustering and it has been an active area of research.

Or Gluster (a free and open source software scalable network filesystem), for a more basic offering that's been out for longer.

Your requirement indicates you really just need regular backups, not something complex, live, simultaneously distributed.
So, your cron-job + rsync approach sounds right. I'd throw in that you probably would want to sync on shutdown, as well. Perfect job for systemd-timers to do the regular execution, and adding the oneshot service job to what gets executed before on shutdown your network gets disconnected. Systemd makes all that easy!
rsync sounds like a fairly good choice here, since it's easy and very transparent – you know what you're keeping synchronized. Restic (for example to an NFS mount or lower-effort to an SSH/SFTP target) is another low-setup alternative.

Systemd is by people who think we still synchronize time, and appear to want linux to be like windows.  I won't touch it.  And shutdown execution isn't viable, as the machine doesn't get shut down.

@DavidG. um, you do realize that none of what you say is technically correct (aside from you not touching systemd, that might be true)? What on earth have you been reading to come to the conclusion that systemd is written by people that want Linux to be like Windows?? Also, please read an answer thoroughly before you rant: "Also on shutdown" doesn't mean "exclusively on shutdown", at all.
